# auth/configuration-not-found, There is no configuration corresponding to the provided identifier. firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-admin

The problem is "simple" but Idk how can I solve it.

I'm working on a firebase app based in NextJS and the problem is in the firebase-admin, this is the error ejected from the server(API):

```
FirebaseAuthError {
    errorInfo: {
      code: 'auth/configuration-not-found',
      message: 'There is no configuration corresponding to the provided identifier.'
    },
    codePrefix: 'auth',
    stack: 'Error: There is no configuration corresponding to the provided identifier.\n' +
      '    at FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (/Users/imac1418/Dev/hotappo-frontend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:146:16)\n' +
      '    at /Users/imac1418/Dev/hotappo-frontend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:1628:49\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)',
    message: 'There is no configuration corresponding to the provided identifier.'
  }
```

my code in the api is simple, only I want get an user by the email:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { AdminApp } from "@tools/initAdmin.app";

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const app = AdminApp();

    app.auth()
        .getUserByEmail("registeredUser@gmail.com")
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));

        res.status(200).json("Ok");
}
```

The API response the "ok" but the catch... catch the error.

Now the intiAdmin.app.ts file:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { getApp } from "firebase-admin/app";

import serviceAccount from "literally the correct path provide by VS code, and if you use cmd+click or ctrl+click you can go to the file";

export function AdminApp() { 
    if (process.env.USE_EMULATORS) {
        process.env["FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = "localhost:5555";
    }

    try {
        getApp()
    } catch {
        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
            databaseURL: process.env.USE_EMULATORS
                ? "http://127.0.0.1:4000/database"
                : "https://enddne-main-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        });

    }

    return admin;
}
```

another important thing, the "serviceAccount" throw an ts error in the `.cert` about incorrect value:

```
Cannot assign an argument of type "{ type: string; project_id: string; private_key_id: string; private_key: string; client_email: string; client_id: string; auth_uri: string; token_uri: string; auth_provider_x509_cert_url: string; client_x509_cert_url: string; universe_domain: string; }" to the parameter of type "string | ServiceAccount". ts(2345)
```

So if I call the API from a button with an `await fetch` for example, the API response `ok` but the "catch" catch this error and don't log the user with this email

- Important things

- I created another service account key provide by firebase to check if the file was the error, but was not it.
- versions dependencies:

```
        "firebase": "^9.22.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.9.0",
    "next": "13.4.2",
    "password-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.10",
    "wrapping-letters-react": "^2.7.4"
```

- the firebase app is initilized
- the fetch is from a button in a form but the button has the `e.preventDefault()`
- the `firebase --version`: 12.3.0 (today I did updated, before was 12.0.idk, the same problem in the old version too)
- device: MacOS Imac 2012 catalina lasted version

Do you need more information? ask me

---

I expected get the user email.

- I tried:

- Convert to string the service account key
- Change the service account key
- Reset the emulators and the next dev script
- I check another post on overflow but the solution don't work to myself
- JSON.parse don't work with the service account key

Comment: Looking at this github issue https://github.com/transistorsoft/background-geolocation-console/issues/121, have you enabled firebase auth in console?